# react-native loading a list of images from gallery using hooks,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im using react native and hooks to make a view where i choose from taking a photo with my camera or open my cellphone gallery and chose any image i want, once i have a picture it should show the image in a list, so if i choose more than one picture it should show more than oneimage in the list.

```
const Seleccion = ({navigation}) => {
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
  const state = useMemo(() => ({ fileList }), [fileList]);

  const onSelectedImage = useCallback((image) => {
    setFileList(fileList => {
      const newDataImg = [...fileList];
      const source = { uri: image.path };
      const item = {
        id: Date.now(),
        url: source,
        content: image.data
      };
      newDataImg.push(item);
      return newDataImg;
    });
  }, [setFileList]);

  const takePhotoFromCamera = useCallback(() => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
    }).then(image => {
      onSelectedImage(image);
      console.log(image);
    });
  }, [onSelectedImage]);

  const choosePhotoFromLibrary = useCallback(() => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
    }).then(image => {
      onSelectedImage(image);
      console.log(image);
    });
  }, [onSelectedImage]);

  const renderItem = useCallback(({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={item.url} style={styles.itemImage} />
      </View>
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={fileList}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        extraData={state}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.viewData} onPress={takePhotoFromCamera}>
        <Text>Foto</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.viewData} onPress={choosePhotoFromLibrary}>
        <Text>galeria</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my dirty component in a sample, take a look at it:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, Fragment} from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5Pro';
import {
  View,
  Modal,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import ActionSheet from 'react-native-action-sheet';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
import ImageViewer from 'react-native-image-zoom-viewer';

import styles from '../../../../../../styles';

const BUTTONS = ['Gallery', 'Camera', 'Cancel'];

export default props => {
  let {files, setFiles} = props;
  const [ImageViwerIsVisible, showImageViwer] = useState(false);
  let [viewingIndex, setViewingIndex] = useState(-1);

  useEffect(() => {
    viewingIndex !== -1 && showImageViwer(true);
  }, [viewingIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    !ImageViwerIsVisible && setViewingIndex(-1);
  }, [ImageViwerIsVisible]);

  const showActionSheet = () =>
    ActionSheet.showActionSheetWithOptions(
      {
        title: 'Choose photo location',
        options: BUTTONS,
        cancelButtonIndex: 2,
        destructiveButtonIndex: 2,
        tintColor: 'blue',
      },
      buttonIndex => {
        switch (buttonIndex) {
          case 0:
            return selectFromGallery();
          case 1:
            return selectFromCamera();
          default:
            return 0;
        }
      },
    );

  const selectFromGallery = () =>
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      multiple: true,
      //cropping: true,
    })
      .then(image => {
        setFiles([...files, image].flat());
      })
      .catch(e => {});
  const selectFromCamera = () =>
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      cropping: true,
      includeExif: true,
    })
      .then(image => {
        setFiles([...files, image]);
      })
      .catch(e => {});
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {!!ImageViwerIsVisible && (
        <Modal transparent={true} onRequestClose={() => showImageViwer(false)}>
          <ImageViewer
            imageUrls={files.map(f => ({url: f.path}))}
            index={viewingIndex}
          />
        </Modal>
      )}
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          padding: 10,
          backgroundColor: '#ececec',
          marginBottom: 5,
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showActionSheet()}>
          <Icon solid name="camera-retro" size={32} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {/* <Text>{JSON.stringify(files, null, 2)}</Text> */}
        <ScrollView style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1}} horizontal>
          {files.map((file, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={file.path}
              onPress={() => setViewingIndex(index)}
              onLongPress={() =>
                ImagePicker.cleanSingle(file.path)
                  .then(() => setFiles(files.filter(f => f.path !== file.path)))
                  .catch(e => {})
              }
              style={{
                marginRight: 5,
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#000',
                borderRadius: 5,
              }}>
              <Image
                source={{uri: file.path}}
                style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', borderRadius: 5}}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

You need to place `useCallBack` as you were use in your code, in that time i was dummy about `react-hooks`.

Comment: srry, i fail into compare your code with mine, i dont even see a sltlist on your code example

Comment: i didn't use list i did use a scroll view, but this is not the point, the key point is how to store multiple images in the state variable.